# Stateless can not resolve to type

Tags: jsp, servlets, ejb

[image]

I simply create one session bean which is of stateless in nature,but it gets error at @Stateless as seen in below image.I am confuse at this stage.Is I have import any jars into my project? or something else,please suggest me any solution.

Comment: Is this a Maven project which we are looking at?

Comment: @BalusC I agree it might be a duplicate, but not of the link you gave.

Comment: @Tim: check OP's question history.

Comment: @BalusC LOL this is a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is not maven project it's a simple dynamic web project for sending email using jsp, servlet, ejb and Tomcat as a Server